# How to redirect *.htm *,htm *,html to *.html in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect `*.htm *,htm *,html` to `*.html`, but when page is `*.html` leave same URL `*.html`.

I have this rule, but there's problem -> redirect loop. What should I change?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.|,)htm(l?)$ $1.html [R=301]
```

Comment: Your pattern matches `.html`, so it will redirect again. You need to handle `*.htm` and `*,htm`, `*,html` separately. Something like `^(.*)(\.htm|,html?)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CBroe rightly commented that issue is with your pattern that also matches `.html` hence will cause a redirect loop.

You can fix it by using:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(.+)(?:\.htm|,html?)$ $1.html [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

PS: This assumes `RewriteBase` directive has been used before.